# using facebook api to get videos to iphone app

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth

I am building an iphone app that reads the videos uploaded , photos uploaded and posts from facebook.
The photos and the videos are not from the feed, they are from the albums. So I got an access token for my app and got it working for the photos and posts. But when I try to get the videos it returns me the following error:

{
   "error": {
      "message": "A user access token is required to request this resource.",
      "type": "OAuthException"
   }
}

the following permissions that I used are: scope=user_about_me,publish_checkins,read_stream,publish_stream,manage_pages,user_videos,offline_access,user_photo_video_tags,user_likes,user_checkins,rsvp_event,user_location,publish_actions

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

What URL are you using for the request?

I was able to retrieve user's uploaded videos using this URL: https://graph.facebook.com/me/videos/uploaded?access_token=myaccesstoken

I used the following permissions: user_videos,offline_access,publish_stream. I think you only need the user_videos to get the user's videos.

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/videos/uploaded?date_format=U&access_token=%@",[authenticationKey_ stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
videoRequest_ = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[videoRequest_ setDelegate:self];
[videoRequest_ startSynchronous];
```

Comment: I am using an app access token, not an acesstoken. but i think with the user access token you should be able to retrieve the photos...

Comment: Im not sure what you are referring to as user access token & app access token. But I am using the same access token for retrieving photos, retrieving videos, uploading photos & videos and it works fine.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7874301/facebook-api-bug @calampunay , if you please answer that question

Comment: @jonypz I am also making a Facebook app, and I would like to know how you got the videos to play. I keep trying but they always return in .flv format which can't be played in iOS. Thanks, Virindh Borra

Comment: @user1320885 This may not be the best solution but what you can do is use the embed_html property so you can play it in a UIWebView